# How to use a messagebox in a event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, messagebox

Context : I have a TreeView in one of my form. Depending on the selection of that TreeView I load a UserControl in a pannel. One pannel is readonly but in the other pannel the user can modifie/add data that I save in a database. If the user try to make a new selection in the TreeView (event BeforeSelect) and he is in the second control (mod/add) and he have unsaved data, I want to ask him if he want to save before loading the new control. The problem is that when the messagebox is shown the event kinda lost the focus and is called in loop (around 20 times). In addition, no matter what the user click on the messagebox (yes save or no just load new control) as no influence.

So my question is : Is there anyway to ask the user what he want to do in the event handler?

I hope i was clear enought, sorry English isn't my first langage

/edit

Here the code from BeforeSelect and IsCtrlFormUnsave

```
private void tv_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsCtrlFormUnsave())
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        //Invoke(new Action(AvertirUser)); //this is in case the save action didn't worked
    }
}

private bool IsCtrlFormUnsave()
{
    if (_ctrlForm != null && _ctrlForm.unsavedChange)
    {
        DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Le formulaire présentement ouvert contient des données qui n'ont pas été sauvegardées. Voulez-vous les enregistrés avant de poursuivre?",
                                                "Attention!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
            if (!_ctrlForm.Save())
                return true;

        _ctrlForm = null;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The function *AvertirUser* only containt a messagebox

Comment: Can you post some example code to help us understand what you're talking about?

Comment: @JesseCarter there you go

Comment: Maybe you need to consider looking into a different event to get the effect you desire. Perhaps plugging into LoseFocus on _ctrlForm before you even allow a new TreeViewItem to become selected

Comment: @JesseCarter user control don't have LoseFocus. I'm trying with Leave event. I think I might be able the get it working properly this way

Comment: TreeView gets **very** cranky when you jerk the focus away in a BeforeSelect event handler.  It is trying to select the node but you won't let it.  It is only safe to display a message box in AfterSelect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Close() method to your **UserControl**, and place the messagebox code there.  Then it can call its own Save() method:

```
    public void Close()
    {
        if (this.unsavedChange)
        {
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Le formulaire présentement ouvert contient des données qui n'ont pas été sauvegardées. Voulez-vous les enregistrés avant de poursuivre?",
                                                    "Attention!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                this.Save();
            }
        }
    }
```

Back in the Form, you can do:

```
    private void tv_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_ctrlForm != null)
        {
            _ctrlForm.Close();
            _ctrlForm.Dispose();
            _ctrlForm = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to check if the selection is the user action or a revert action of user cancel etc.

one way of fixing it is to add another `bool` value:

```
bool IsChecked=false;
private void tv_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsChecked && IsCtrlFormUnsave()) //Check if it's already confirmed with the user
    {
        e.Cancel = true;           
    }
}

private bool IsCtrlFormUnsave()
{
    IsChecked=true; //set it to true to jump out of the loop
    if (_ctrlForm != null && _ctrlForm.unsavedChange)
    {   

        DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Le formulaire présentement ouvert contient des données qui n'ont pas été sauvegardées. Voulez-vous les enregistrés avant de poursuivre?",
                                                "Attention!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
            if (!_ctrlForm.Save())
                return true;

        _ctrlForm = null;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And remember to reset `IsChecked=false` when you load `second control` again.